# How to make a synchronus calls in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, synchronous

I am trying to parse excel file data from files to mysql db but i will do it for many files but due to asynchronous property of nodejs before completing the  task for first file it interrupts for second file so is there any way to make this functionality synchronous.

My nodejs code:

```
while (typeof issue.fields.attachment[r] != "undefined") {
    if (typeof issue.fields.attachment[r].content != "undefined") {
        var url = issue.fields.attachment[r].content;
        console.log('url :' + url);
        request({
                method: "GET",
                "rejectUnauthorized": false,
                "url": url,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "Basic" +
                }
            },
            function(err, data, body) {
                //console.log(data.body);
                console.log('file downloading');
            }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.xlsx'));
        console.log('file downloaded');
        parseXlsx('file.xlsx', function(err, data) {});
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want it to be synchronous, you want it to be in series.  Huge difference.

Comment: i want it to be in series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the contents of a while call execute in series pretty easily with async's whilst method. You wrap your condition in an anonymous function and pass that as the first argument, your while's content in another anonymous function and pass that as the second argument.  You then call a callback when your while's work is done each time, and that is how it knows to loop.

```
var async = require('async');
async.whilst(function(){return typeof issue.fields.attachment[r] !== "undefined"},function(callback){
    if(typeof issue.fields.attachment[r].content != "undefined")
    {
        var url = issue.fields.attachment[r].content ;
        console.log('url :'+url);
        var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('file.xlsx');
        request({
            method: "GET", 
            "rejectUnauthorized": false, 
            "url": url,
            "headers" :{
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic"+ 
            }
        },function(err,data,body){
            //console.log(data.body);
            console.log('file downloading'); 
        }).pipe(wstream);
        wstream.on('finish',function(){
            parseXlsx('file.xlsx', function(err, data){
                return callback();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

You will want to put in some error handling.  If you call callback() with an err, it will stop looping, so if you want it to continue despite an error, you just call callback();

Note:I also fixed up some of your writestream code.

Comment: @ trex005 my code is incomplete here means there are so many more callbacks in my code can you help me in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823925/how-to-make-a-while-loop-in-nodejs-to-be-a-series

Answer (score 1):

You can create Promises for each task that you wish to execute in series.
Then its just a simple chaining  of the promises to execute the tasks in series.